# Windows Forms popup wtih context menu behaviour

Tags: c#, winforms, events, popup, contextmenu

**I want to create a popup in Window Forms which behaves like a context menu.**

I need to display additional fields on click. These fields should be displayed inside an popup/overlay (either implemented as a separate form or a UserControl, I'm ok with both). **That overlay should appear on click and disappear on every action that would make a context menu disappear**.

What is the easiest way to do that? I have several nested control on the form and I would like to avoid attaching events to every one of them... (besides im not even sure which events to listen to)

Comment: You didn't quite explain why a context menu wouldn't work for your situation...

Comment: Sorry for the delay. A context menu can't contain textboxes, can it?